# Number of induced subforests in a a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Whilst working on my master thesis I would find it usefull if the number of induced subforests (up to isomorphism) of a tree of size $n$ would be bound by a polynomial in $n$. I've got no good way to prove this. Does anyone have any hints/ ideas on how to prove/disprove this?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(n)$ is the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) - the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of positive integers, ignoring order - then the $n$-vertex path has at least $p(\lceil n/2\rceil)$ induced subforests. If $a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_k$ is a partition of $\lceil n/2\rceil$, there is an induced subforest whose components are paths with $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ vertices. (We only go up to $\lceil n/2\rceil$, because in order to obtain this subforest, we have to skip $k-1$ vertices between its components.)

According to Wikipedia, we have $$p(n) \sim \frac1{4n\sqrt 3} \exp\left(\pi \sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}\right),$$ so the number of induced subforests of the $n$-vertex path grows faster than polynomially.

Comment: This is not what I asked for because this set of subforests might contain duplicates which I don't want.

Comment: It does not contain duplicates. Isomorphic subforests would give us the same partition. For example, there is only one partition $1+1+2+2$ (assuming $n\ge 11$) corresponding to a subforest with two paths of length $2$ and two paths of length $1$. The sum $1+2+1+2$ (which would indeed give the same subforest) is not a different partition; it is a different way to write the same partition, and these are only counted once by $p(\lceil n/2\rceil)$.

Comment: I get it now, thanks a lot!